# select from each group

Tags: sql, sql-server

Sample table

```
SELECT * FROM MachineMaster

MachineID | MachineName | BatchID  | StatusID | domainid
1         | Test1       | 50       | 500      | 1  
2         | Test2       | 50       | 500      | 2    
3         | Test3       | 50       | 500      | 1    
4         | Test4       | 50       | 500      | 2    
5         | Test5       | 50       | 500      | 3
```

I would like `SELECT * WHERE statusid = 500` and `SELECT one domain id` from each batch. Here is what I would like to see..

```
  MachineID | MachineName | BatchID  | StatusID | domainid
    1       | Test1       | 50       | 500      | 1   
    3       | Test3       | 50       | 500      | 1
```

Comment: which domain id, random one? what have you tried?

Comment: `WHERE domainid = 1` ?

Comment: Your example has all rows with same BatchID, and output have two rows. That does not really correspond to your explanation of the matter?

Comment: do you mean `SELECT * FROM MachineMaster WHERE StatusID = 500 AND domainid = 1` ?

Comment: "One domain from each batch" - I think you need to make your example have two different batch numbers.

Comment: @vikramathare Clear the Question with required output exactly you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a sub query that adds the minimum domain id per batch, and then filter on that:

```
select MachineID,MachineName,BatchID,StatusID,domainid
from   (
        select *,
               min(domainid) over (partition by BatchID) as mindomainid
        from   MachineMaster
        where  StatusID = 500
        ) base
where   domainid = mindomainid
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems so easy unless you want something else -

```
SELECT * 
FROM MachineMaster
WHERE StatusID = 500
AND domainid = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a tricky way of doing this without a subquery:

```
SELECT TOP (1) WITH TIES t.*
FROM t
WHERE statusid = 500
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY domainid ORDER BY domainid);
```